# How to count occurrences of each character?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

For example I have file `1.txt`, that contain:

```
Moscow
Astana
Tokyo
Ottawa
```

I want to count number of all char as:

```
a - 4,
b - 0,
c - 1,
...
z - 0
```

Comment: From the accepted answer, it is not completely clear, do you want "A" and "a" distinguished or not? your question suggests you do.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use this:

```
sed 's/./&\n/g' 1.txt | sort | uniq -ic
  4  
  5 a
  1 c
  1 k
  1 M
  1 n
  5 o
  2 s
  4 t
  2 w
  1 y
```

The `sed` part places a newline after every character. Then we `sort` the ouput alphabetically. And at last `uniq` counts the number of occurences. The `-i` flag of `uniq` can be ommited if you don't want case insensitivity.

Comment: This is brilliant. An extra caveat would be to pipe the output again into `sort -k 2` to list them alphanumerically.

Comment: This is the shortest way, most understandable but ufortunately the slowest

Comment: On Mac OS X I had to use `sed -e $'s/\(.\)/\\1\\\n/g'` (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/18410122/179014)

Comment: To order by the number of occurrences (descending): `| sort -rnk 1`. And if you're dealing with very large files, like I am, you can just sample a few thousand line to get a proxy for the actual counts: `cat 1.txt | shuf -n 10000 | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | sort | uniq -ic | sort -rnk 1`

Answer (score 6):

A bit late, but to complete the set, another python(3) approach, sorted result:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

chars = open(sys.argv[1]).read().strip().replace("\n", "")
[print(c+" -", chars.count(c)) for c in sorted(set([c for c in chars]))]

A - 1
M - 1
O - 1
T - 1
a - 4
c - 1
k - 1
n - 1
o - 4
s - 2
t - 3
w - 2
y - 1
```

#### Explanation

1. Read the file, skip spaces and returns as "characters":

   ```
   chars = open(sys.argv[1]).read().strip().replace("\n", "")
   ```
2. Create a (sorted) set of uniques:

   ```
   sorted(set([c for c in chars]))
   ```
3. Count and print the occurrence for each of the characters:

   ```
   print(c+" -", chars.count(c)) for c in <uniques>
   ```

#### How to use

1. Paste the code into an empty file, save it as `chars_count.py`
2. Run it with the file as an argument by either:

   ```
   /path/to/chars_count.py </path/to/file>
   ```

   if the script is executable, or:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/chars_count.py </path/to/file>
   ```

   if it isn't

Answer (score 6):

By default in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) the **F**ield **S**eparator (FS) is *space* or *tab*. Since we want to count each character, we will have to redefine the FS to nothing(`FS=""`) to split each character in separate line and save it into an array and at the end inside`END{..}` block, print their total occurrences by the following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command:

```bsh
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END{for (c in a) print c,a[c]}' FS="" file
A 1
M 1
O 1
T 1
a 4
c 1
k 1
n 1
o 4
s 2
t 3
w 2
y 1
```

In `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} ... FS="" ...` block we just splits the characters. And
in `END{for (c in a) print c,a[c]}` block we are looping to array `a` and printing saved character in it `print c` and its number of occurrences `a[c]`

Comment: This answer is much faster/better than the accepted one (which reads through the file 3 times and does an unnecessary sort). No need for any of that, just read through the file once and increment a counter for each character, then print a report at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Do a `for` loop for all the characters you want to count, and use `grep -io` to get all occurences of the character and ignoring case, and `wc -l` to count instances, and print the result.

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="1.txt"

for char in {a..z}
do
    echo "${char} - `grep -io "${char}" ${filename} | wc -l`,"
done
```

The script outputs this:

```
a - 5,
b - 0,
c - 1,
d - 0,
e - 0,
f - 0,
g - 0,
h - 0,
i - 0,
j - 0,
k - 1,
l - 0,
m - 1,
n - 1,
o - 5,
p - 0,
q - 0,
r - 0,
s - 2,
t - 4,
u - 0,
v - 0,
w - 2,
x - 0,
y - 1,
z - 0,
```

**EDIT after comment**

To create a loop for all printable characters you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="a.txt"

for num in {32..126}
do
   char=`printf "\x$(printf %x ${num})"`
   echo "${char} - `grep -Fo "${char}" ${filename} | wc -l`,"
done
```

This will count all ANSI characters from 32 to 126 - these are the most commonly readable ones. Note that this does not use ignore case.

output from this will be:

```
- 0,
! - 0,
" - 0,
# - 0,
$ - 0,
% - 0,
& - 0,
' - 0,
( - 0,
) - 0,
* - 0,
+ - 0,
, - 0,
- - 0,
. - 0,
/ - 0,
0 - 0,
1 - 0,
2 - 0,
3 - 0,
4 - 0,
5 - 0,
6 - 0,
7 - 0,
8 - 0,
9 - 0,
: - 0,
; - 0,
< - 0,
= - 0,
> - 0,
? - 0,
@ - 0,
A - 1,
B - 0,
C - 0,
D - 0,
E - 0,
F - 0,
G - 0,
H - 0,
I - 0,
J - 0,
K - 0,
L - 0,
M - 1,
N - 0,
O - 1,
P - 0,
Q - 0,
R - 0,
S - 0,
T - 1,
U - 0,
V - 0,
W - 0,
X - 0,
Y - 0,
Z - 0,
[ - 0,
\ - 0,
] - 0,
^ - 0,
_ - 0,
` - 0,
a - 4,
b - 0,
c - 1,
d - 0,
e - 0,
f - 0,
g - 0,
h - 0,
i - 0,
j - 0,
k - 1,
l - 0,
m - 0,
n - 1,
o - 4,
p - 0,
q - 0,
r - 0,
s - 2,
t - 3,
u - 0,
v - 0,
w - 2,
x - 0,
y - 1,
z - 0,
{ - 0,
| - 0,
} - 0,
~ - 0,
```

Comment: If you dont want to ignore case then remove the `i` from the grep. (in your question you had only 3 in the expected result)

Comment: oh, thanks. "{a..z}" - it's all symbols from 'a' to 'z'? what about all printable symbols, how we can designate them without listing all of them

Comment: Ive updated my answer with an example on how to extend the search for all readable characters

Comment: That's a _lot_ of calls to `grep` the entire input repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

Here another solution (in awk)...

```
awk '
        { for (indx=length($0); indx >= 1; --indx)
                ++chars[tolower(substr($0, indx, 1))]
        }
END     { for (c in chars) print c, chars[c]; }
' 1.txt | sort
```

- It creates an associative array with each character as the index value and the count as the array value.
- The END action prints the array.

Comment: no need to `cat file | awk '...'`: you can directly say `awk '...' file`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import collections, string
with open('1.txt') as f:
    input_string = f.read().replace('\n', '').lower()
    count_dict = collections.Counter(input_string)
    for char in string.lowercase:
        print char + ' - ' + str(count_dict[char]) + ','
```

Here we have used the `collections` module's `Counter` class to count the number of occurrences of each character, then for printing purpose we have used the `string` module to get all the lowercase letters by the variable `string.lowercase`.

Save the above script in a file giving it any name you want e.g. `count.py`. Now from the same directory where the file is saved you can simply run `python count.py` to execute the file, from any other directory use the absolute path to the file to execute it i.e. `python /absolute/path/to/count.py`.

Comment: Could you please clarify your solution. I mean: create file file_name, put this code, chmod +x etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @c0rp: done....

Answer (score 2):

The following `perl` oneliner will do the count. I put the regex in list context (to get the number of matches) and put that into scalar context:

```
$ perl -e '$a=join("",<>);for("a".."z"){$d=()=$a=~/$_/gi;print"$_ - $d,\n"}' 1.txt
a - 5,
b - 0,
c - 1,
d - 0,
e - 0,
f - 0,
g - 0,
h - 0,
i - 0,
j - 0,
k - 1,
l - 0,
m - 1,
n - 1,
o - 5,
p - 0,
q - 0,
r - 0,
s - 2,
t - 4,
u - 0,
v - 0,
w - 2,
x - 0,
y - 1,
z - 0,
```

Comment: To get rid of the trailing comma seems to require a significant rewrite: `perl -Mfeature=say -e '$a=join("",<>);say join(",\n", map { sprintf("%s - %d", $_, ($d=()=$a=~/$_/gi)); } ("a".."z"))'`

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I wrote a C program to do that, because I needed it to look at *large* files and produce some statics.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sysexits.h>


inline static double square(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}


int main()
{
    static const unsigned distribution_size = 1 << CHAR_BIT;

    int rv = EX_OK;
    uintmax_t *distribution = calloc(distribution_size, sizeof(*distribution));

    {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
            distribution[c]++;

        if (ferror(stdin)) {
            perror("I/O error on standard input");
            rv = EX_IOERR;
        }
    }

    uintmax_t sum = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != distribution_size; i++)
        sum += distribution[i];
    double avg = (double) sum / distribution_size;

    double var_accum = 0.0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != distribution_size; i++)
    {
        const uintmax_t x = distribution[i];

        printf("'%c' (%02X): %20ju", isprint((int) i) ? i : ' ', i, x);
        if (x != 0) {
            var_accum += square((double) x - avg);
            printf(" (%+.2e %%)\n", ((double) x / avg - 1.0) * 100.0);
        } else {
            var_accum += square(avg);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    double stdev = sqrt(var_accum / distribution_size);
    double varcoeff = stdev / avg;
    printf(
        "total: %ju\n"
        "average: %e\n"
        "standard deviation: %e\n"
        "variation coefficient: %e\n",
        sum, avg, stdev, varcoeff);

    free(distribution);
    return rv;
}
```

compile with (assuming the source code resides in `character-distribution.c`):

```
cc -std=c99 -O2 -g0 -o character-distribution character-distribution.c
```

run with:

```
./character-distribution < 1.txt
```

If you don't have a C compiler ready, install GCC:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc build-essential
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer using ruby. It is done by changing the string into a uniq list of the different characters and using the count method on each of them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

String content = IO.read("1.txt")
content.split("").uniq.sort.each { |chr| puts( chr + ' - ' + content.count(chr).to_s) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution to @heemayl, with tighter code, which works on Python 2.7 and Python 3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import collections
import fileinput
import itertools
import string

count = collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*fileinput.input()))
print(',\n'.join('{} - {}'.format(c, count[c] + count[c.upper()])
                 for c in string.ascii_lowercase))
```

The first statement, `count = collections.Counter(…)` does all the real work.

- `fileinput.input()` reads every line of the input, which may be piped via stdin or as command-line arguments.
- `*` makes it consider a character at a time rather than a line at a time.
- `count = Counter(…)` counts occurrences of each character efficiently, in a single pass, and stores the result in the `count` variable.

The second line just prints the results.

- `'{} - {}'.format(c, count[c] + count[c.upper()]) for c in string.ascii_lowercase` makes a list of each character and its count.
- `print(',\n'.join(…))` puts it in the desired format: one per line, separated by commas, but no comma on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk 4.1

```
awk -iwalkarray '{for (;NF;NF--) b[$NF]++} END {walk_array(b)}' FS=
```

```
[A] = 1
[O] = 1
[w] = 2
[k] = 1
[y] = 1
[T] = 1
[n] = 1
[a] = 4
[o] = 4
[c] = 1
[s] = 2
[t] = 3
[M] = 1
```

If you have earlier version of GNU awk you can use `for (c in b) print c, b[c]`.